NestJS, SocketIo clusterization with redis streams adapter and sticky sessions
I want to implement clusterization in my NestJs and SocketIo app, and for this like I understand I must implement an Adapter(I had choose Redis Streams) and sticky sessions.I get stuck with clusterization and sticky sessions.How should I implement these sticky sessions?
I have implemented the redis streams adapter looks like this:
import { IoAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-socket.io/adapters';
import { ServerOptions } from 'socket.io';
import { RedisClientType, createClient } from 'redis';
import { createAdapter } from '@socket.io/redis-streams-adapter';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { IRedisConfig } from 'src/common/interfaces/redis.config.interface';
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';

export class RedisStreamsAdapter extends IoAdapter {
  private redisClient: RedisClientType;
  private readonly logger = new Logger(RedisStreamsAdapter.name);
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {
    super(configService);
  }

  async connectRedis() {
    await this.redisClient.connect();
  }

  createIOServer(port: number, options?: ServerOptions): any {
    const redisCofig = this.configService.get<IRedisConfig>('redisConfig');
    this.redisClient = createClient({
      url: `redis://:${redisCofig.password}@${redisCofig.host}:${redisCofig.port}`,
    });

    const server: Server = super.createIOServer(port, options);
    this.connectRedis()
      .then(() => {
        const redisAdapter = createAdapter(this.redisClient);
        server.adapter(redisAdapter);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.logger.error(error, error.stack);
      });

    return server;
  }
}


and I use it in main.ts file  app.useWebSocketAdapter(new RedisStreamsAdapter(configService));
